# How to write formula as column using columns in sql select stataement

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: This my result of query]
I want to get result as Available column as using formula
 `(RAC + RAPO) - (IAC + IAPO + PR)`.

Following is my query:

```
SELECT c.Id,ic.Title as ItemClass,s.Title as SubCategory,m.Title as MainCategory,c.Title as Item,c.LongDescription,u.Title,
(SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAC,
(SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstPO' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAPO,
(SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueToCompany' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as ITC,
(SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as IAC,
(SELECT SUM(pd.Qty) FROM M_PurchaseReturn_D pd INNER JOIN M_PurchaseReturn_M pr ON pd.M_PurchaseReturn_M_Id=pr.Id WHERE pd.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as PR 
FROM COP_Item_Id c 
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Sub_Category s ON c.COP_SubCategory_Id=s.Id
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Main_Category m ON s.Item_Main_Category_Id=m.Id
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Class ic ON m.Item_Class_Id=ic.Id 
INNER JOIN INV_Product_Unit u ON c.INV_ProductUnit_Id=u.Id Order by C.Id ASC
```

Comment: What is the problem with your query, what exactly are you asking? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: i want to get Column Available as Columns (RAC+RAPO)-(ITC+IAC+PR) 
I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Without CTE:

```
select x.*, 
    (isnull(x.RAC,0) + isnull(x.RAPO,0))-(isnull(x.IAC,0) + isnull(x.IAPO,0) + isnull(PR,0)) as Available
from (
    SELECT c.Id,ic.Title as ItemClass,s.Title as SubCategory,m.Title as MainCategory,c.Title as Item,c.LongDescription,u.Title,
        (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAC,
        (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstPO' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAPO,
        (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueToCompany' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as ITC,
        (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as IAC,
        (SELECT SUM(pd.Qty) FROM M_PurchaseReturn_D pd INNER JOIN M_PurchaseReturn_M pr ON pd.M_PurchaseReturn_M_Id=pr.Id WHERE pd.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as PR 
    FROM COP_Item_Id c 
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Sub_Category s ON c.COP_SubCategory_Id=s.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Main_Category m ON s.Item_Main_Category_Id=m.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Class ic ON m.Item_Class_Id=ic.Id 
    INNER JOIN INV_Product_Unit u ON c.INV_ProductUnit_Id=u.Id
) x
Order by x.Id ASC
```

Comment: Error : Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @AyeshaSheikh, since this answer worked, please [mark it so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).  (And you might do the same for any answers that worked on your other questions.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

using `cte`:-

```
    ; with cte as (
    SELECT c.Id,ic.Title as ItemClass,s.Title as SubCategory,m.Title as MainCategory,c.Title as Item,c.LongDescription,u.Title,
    (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAC,
    (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstPO' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as RAPO,
    (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueToCompany' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as ITC,
    (SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as IAC,
    (SELECT SUM(pd.Qty) FROM M_PurchaseReturn_D pd INNER JOIN M_PurchaseReturn_M pr ON pd.M_PurchaseReturn_M_Id=pr.Id WHERE pd.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) as PR 
    FROM COP_Item_Id c 
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Sub_Category s ON c.COP_SubCategory_Id=s.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Main_Category m ON s.Item_Main_Category_Id=m.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Class ic ON m.Item_Class_Id=ic.Id 
    INNER JOIN INV_Product_Unit u ON c.INV_ProductUnit_Id=u.Id 
    )
    select * , (isnull(RAC,0) + isnull(RAPO,0)) - (isnull(IAC,0) + isnull(IAPO,0) + isnull(PR,0)) as [colname] from cte
```

in place of `*` mention your column names required.

And if you don't need these calculate column then try this:-

```
    SELECT c.Id,ic.Title as ItemClass,s.Title as SubCategory,m.Title as MainCategory,c.Title as Item,c.LongDescription,u.Title,
    isnull((SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id),0) +
    isnull((SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='RecieveAgainstPO' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id),0) +
    isnull((SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueToCompany' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id),0) +
    isnull((SELECT SUM(md.Qty) FROM M_MIR_D md INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id WHERE m.Type='IssueAgainstContract' AND md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id),0) +
    isnull((SELECT SUM(pd.Qty) FROM M_PurchaseReturn_D pd INNER JOIN M_PurchaseReturn_M pr ON pd.M_PurchaseReturn_M_Id=pr.Id WHERE pd.COP_Item_Id=c.Id),0) as [ColName]
    FROM COP_Item_Id c 
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Sub_Category s ON c.COP_SubCategory_Id=s.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Main_Category m ON s.Item_Main_Category_Id=m.Id
    INNER JOIN COP_Item_Class ic ON m.Item_Class_Id=ic.Id 
    INNER JOIN INV_Product_Unit u ON c.INV_ProductUnit_Id=u.Id Order by C.Id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with `APPLY`

```
SELECT c.Id,ic.Title as ItemClass,s.Title as SubCategory,m.Title as MainCategory,c.Title as Item,c.LongDescription,u.Title
, t1.RAC, t1.RAPO, t1.IAC, t1.IAPO, t2.PR
, (t1.RAC+t1.RAPO)-(t1.IAC+t1.IAPO+ t2.PR) Res
FROM COP_Item_Id c 
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Sub_Category s ON c.COP_SubCategory_Id=s.Id
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Main_Category m ON s.Item_Main_Category_Id=m.Id
INNER JOIN COP_Item_Class ic ON m.Item_Class_Id=ic.Id 
INNER JOIN INV_Product_Unit u ON c.INV_ProductUnit_Id=u.Id 
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(CASE m.Type WHEN 'RecieveAgainstContract' THEN md.Qty END) as RAC
        , SUM(CASE m.Type WHEN 'RecieveAgainstPO' THEN md.Qty END) as RAPO
        , SUM(CASE m.Type WHEN 'IssueToCompany' THEN md.Qty END) as ITC
        , SUM(CASE m.Type WHEN 'IssueAgainstContract' THEN md.Qty END) as IAC
   FROM M_MIR_D md 
   INNER JOIN M_MIR_M m ON md.M_MIR_M_Id=m.Id 
   WHERE md.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) t1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT SUM(pd.Qty) as PR 
   FROM M_PurchaseReturn_D pd 
   INNER JOIN M_PurchaseReturn_M pr ON pd.M_PurchaseReturn_M_Id=pr.Id 
   WHERE pd.COP_Item_Id=c.Id) t2
Order by C.Id ASC
```